# How to disable the "71 keys pressed in the last..." Window

Tags: autohotkey

I have an NKRO keyboard, so when I hold down a bunch of keys, sometimes when gaming, the "71 keys pressed in the last ____ seconds" window pops up from AHK. Is there a way that I can disable that window or remove it from the AHK program altogether?

Comment: Are you actually using all these hotkeys, or is there something wrong with the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoHotkey has two directives for controlling this behavior:

1. [`#MaxHotkeysPerInterval <Value>`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MaxHotkeysPerInterval.htm)

This lets you define how many hotkeys can be fired within a certain interval (see below) before the warning dialog comes up.  The default is 70.

2. [`#HotkeyInterval <Milliseconds>`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_HotkeyInterval.htm)

This lets you define the length of the interval describe above in milliseconds.  The default is 2000, which is 2 seconds.

This warning popup is in place to protect you, so don't overdo it with these directives.  They are intended to prevent you from creating an infinite loop where a hotkey triggers itself.  70 hotkeys within 2 seconds is quite a lot for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 9999` to the top of your script. If that doesn't work, it might be useful to know what scripts are using in case those are contributing to the problem.

[Source](//autohotkey.com/board/topic/80228-71-hotkeys-have-been-received-in-the-last-x-seconds/?p=509718)

Answer (score 0):

Per help docs this works
Place it in the beginning of the script

A_HotkeyInterval := 2000  ; This is the default value (milliseconds).
A_MaxHotkeysPerInterval := 200